# If $\overline f=f-f'(a)$ then how is $\overline {f'(a)}=0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations

Below is the definition of a function being differentiable at a point, given in my notes:

> A function $f:A \rightarrow Y$ is said to be differentiable at $a \in A$ if there is a linear map $T \in L(X,Y) ,$ such that 
>                  lim$_{r \to 0}\frac{\|f(a+r)-f(a)-T\text{r}\|}{\|\text{r}\|}=0$.
>
> It is called the derivative of $f$ at $a \in A$.  Note that $f'(a)$ is a linear operator and its value at $x\in X$ is $f'(a)(x)\in Y$

Now I had a proof in which I had to define $\overline f=f-f'(a)$ and then it is given that $\overline {f'(a)}=0$. But I can't understand how is $\overline {f'(a)}=0$?

Kindly if anyone can help me with this..

Comment: What do you mean by "then *it is given* that $\overline f'(a)=0$"? Are you supposed to prove that statement? If yes, I'm pretty sure the statement is actually false, since $f'(a)$ is just a constant and shifting a function $f$ by a constant (as in $\overline f$) does not affect its derivative at all. Therefore, with the information you give in your question, $\overline f'(a)=0$ iif $f'(a)=0$.

Comment: @pew yes I'm required to conclude:$\overline f'(a)=0$ ? given $f:E\to \mathbb R^n$ is a $C^1$ map.but I think the statement must be true as it is written corectly in my study material in the proof given in inverse function theorem

Comment: @pew and how is $f'(a)$ just a constant..

Comment: Let $E=\mathbb R$ and $n=1$. Then $f$ is simply $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and your definition of the derivative matches the standard one used in real analysis. Now choose $f:x\rightarrow x^2$ and $a=1$. Then $f'(a)=2$, so $\overline f(x)=x^2-2$, and $\overline f'(a)=2\ne 0$. So as before, the statement is false with what is given.

Comment: this explanation is awkward, I do not quite believe it but here it is. Perhaps they mean they could plug any function in that definition, e.g. instead if $f$, say $\overline g=g-f'(a)$ (here $f'(a)$ is just a fixed constant). So, in particular the function $f'$ could play the role of $f$ (or of $g$), then we get $\overline{f'}=f'-f'(a)$. Then evaluate at $a$, we get $\overline{f'}(a)=f'(a)-f'(a)=0$. At least I got the right answer :)

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko I can't understand how you wrote here $f'(a)$ is just a fixed constant....Isn't it a linear map?

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko: So you're saying that $\overline f'=\overline{(f')}$, where "overline" is an operator on functions... somehow, I find that hard to believe :)

Comment: @coool: $f'$ is a linear map. $f'(a)$ is that linear map, evaluated at $a$, giving a fixed value.

Comment: @coool: In light of that confusion, maybe you really mean $\overline f = f - f'$?

Comment: @pew :yes I mean $\overline f = f - f'(a)$...but in response to your reply to my doubt where did I specify $f'(a)$ to be constant in question..

Comment: @coool: But $f-f'(a)\ne f-f'$!

Comment: @pew but I specified $\overline f=f-f'(a)$ already in my question and nowhere did I use: $\overline f=f-f'$

Comment: @coool: As I showed in my comment above, using the definition $\overline f = f - f'(a)$ the claim $\overline f'(a)=0$ is false in general.

Comment: @pew But I have another doubt .It is from which condition in my question should I conclude $f′(a)$ to be constant..

Comment: @coool: $f'(a)$ is $f'$, evaluated at $a$. Since $a$ is not the independent variable of the function $\overline f$ (overwise it would be written as $\overline{f}(a)$), $f'(a)$ is a constant in the context of $\overline f$. I'm afraid that's really all I can do to explain that.

Comment: @pew it might be that $f'(a)$ is a linear map, it is not yet evaluated at anything, but it could be evaluated at say $t$, like in $f'(a)(t)$